# swap using a macro in c but there is an error

Tags: c

i am trying to understand macro in c.
i had found this program as a question to extract the error
obviously it need to swap the numbers using exclusive or (i can not also understand why using xor to swap)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SWAP(a, b) { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b;}
int main(void) {
int x = 10;
int y = 5;
int z = 4;
if (x < 0)
 SWAP(x, y);
else
 SWAP(x, z);
}
```

the compiler popped an error to include if before else.
but obviously there is an if before else
i want to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: Remove the `;` after the macro calls. Or add braces to the `if/else` blocks.

Comment: Definitely add braces to the `if` and `else` blocks.  Using braces routinely, even for single-statement blocks, protects you against a variety of oddities and potential mistakes.

Comment: Also, if you are going to write a macro whose expansion itself contains a code block, then a widespread idiom is to structure it as a `do { ... } while (0)`.  That would work for you without removing the semicolons, but you should still (also) use braces around the `if` and `else` bodies.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: Don't ever swap like this.  It's **hugely** inefficient if it's not optimized out (count the store and bitwise operations compared to "load a in r1, load b in r2, store r2 in a, store r1 in b" of a sane swap with a temp value). And with signed integer values in C it risks undefined behavior. Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C, and the intermediate values could result in a value outside the range of a valid signed integer value - or signed integer overflow.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Note, thought, that the C example on that Wiki page risks undefined behavior.

Comment: See also [Why use apparently meaningless `do`/`while` and `if`/`else` in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/15168)

Comment: @AndrewHenle The C example would have been better wih `unsigned`, I agree. But, is "overflow" a concern with bitwise XOR? That'd be news to me... Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `;` after `SWAP(x, y)`.

Once the macro substitution is performed by the preprocessor, here's what the code looks like (with the `;` moved to a separate line for illustrative purposes):

```
if (x < 0)
 { x ^= y; y ^= x; x ^= y;}
 ;
else
 { x ^= z; z ^= x; x ^= z;}
 ;
```

The block in `{` `}` after the `if` is valid, and technically so is it the `;`, but it makes the `else` invalid syntax.

As the comments indicate, the best fix is to remove the `;`, but also put the `if`/`else` blocks in braces, like this:

```
if (x < 0) {
 SWAP(x, y)
} else {
 SWAP(x, z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a semicolon after closing braces:

```
{ ... };
       ^ here
```

The C grammar does not allow that. The solution is using `do {} while (0)` trick. Which a dummy loop that is always executed once and it allows a semicolon after it.

Just define your macro as:

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b;} while (0)
```